# 2 projectors + internal screen on Lenovo x230 Tablet?

Tags: windows-7, graphics, tablet, projector

I teach 100+ classes every year on fraud and ethics. I often need to write notes but people in the back of the room can't see the flipchart.

So I want to connect 2 projectors: One would show my pptx slides, and the second would show a PowerPoint file with 25 blanks slides to write on as my electronic flipchart.

To do that I need both projectors live AND have the laptop screen active so I can write on it with the pen. So far no one has been able to tell me how to do it. Ideas?

I'm using Windows 7 Home Premium.

Answer (score 0):

Get a [docking station for that tablet](http://www.lenovo.com/support/docks) that supports more than one monitor, and hook the projectors up to those monitor ports.

Alternatively, look into using one or two [DisplayLink USB video adapters](http://www.displaylink.com/shop/adapters) that are compatible with your projectors' input.